# ReactJS - React Router calling Function in Nested Component from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to call my Nested Components function from my Parent Component and I continue to get the following error returned to my console:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.props.handleTouchTap is not a function**

I personally struggle with .props, I imagine it is a simple error to fix but for some reason I can't seem to figure out what I have to do.

What I want my code to do is this:
 - When the user is updating their info, after the update has been posted to Firebase I would like a material-ui snackbar to pop-up stating that.
- I have declared the snackbar in the child component, and it is working. What I can't do is toggle the state which controls the snackbar from the Parent Component.

React Routes:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route component={Profile}>
      <Route path="/profile" component={Child} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```

Child Component:

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      message: "Update Successful!!",
    };
  }

  handleTouchTap(){
    this.setState({
      open: true,
    });
  };

  handleRequestClose(){
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
          <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <Drawer />
                <Snackbar
                  open={this.state.open}
                  message={this.state.message}
                  autoHideDuration={4000}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
                />
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      address: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
    }
  },

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getUserDetails();
  },

  getUserDetails: function(){
    var personID = this.param('id'); 
    if(personID.length > 0){
      new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/' + personID).on('value', function(snap) {
       this.setState({
          name: snap.val().Name,
          surname: snap.val().Surname,
          address: snap.val().Address,
          phone: snap.val().Phone,
          email: snap.val().Email
        });

      }.bind(this));
     }
  },

  updateDetails: function(){
    var personID = this.param('id'); 
    if(personID.length > 0){
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + personID).update({
          Name: this.state.name,
          Surname: this.state.surname,
          Address: this.state.address,
          Phone: this.state.phone,
          Email: this.state.email
      });
      this.props.handleTouchTap();
     }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
         ....
        <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.updateDetails}>Update</Button> 
         ....
         ...
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Where are you passing the `handleTouchTap` prop to the `Parent` component? If `Profile` is your parent component you are not passing this property anywhere.

Comment: @tiagohngl I made a slight edit up above, I forgot to include it. I assumed I passed it to Profile, which is the parent, using {this.props.children}.

Comment: I suggest you read the React documentation, you are clearly missing some core concepts. Try to understand how `props` work with simple examples before you go into complex components.